# How to declare a record on a user-defined type in postgres

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, record

I have a snippet of code in Oracle, creating a variable of Record type

```
  TYPE t_article IS RECORD (article_id sch.article.article_id%TYPE,
                            short_article_title sch.article.short_article_title%TYPE,
                            short_article_text  sch.article.short_article_text%TYPE,
                            pub_ts sch.article.pub_ts%TYPE,
                            paren_info VARCHAR2(500),
                            article_date        sch.article.article_date%TYPE);
        v_article_rec       t_article;
```

How can I declare the above code to create a user defined Record in Postgres?

I tried using below code in Postgres,

```
TYPE  v_article_rec as (article_id sch.article.article_id%TYPE,
                        short_article_title sch.article.short_article_title%TYPE,
                        short_article_text  sch.article.short_article_text%TYPE,
                        pub_ts sch.article.pub_ts%TYPE,
                        paren_info VARCHAR2(500),
                        article_date sch.article.article_date%TYPE);
```

But I am getting an syntax error. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In postgres you can just declare a record *`name RECORD`*

> Record variables are similar to row-type variables, but they have no predefined structure. They take on the actual row structure of the row they are assigned during a SELECT or FOR command

[Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-declarations.html)